# What's the name for enqueue and dequeue done together?

Tags: queue, naming-conventions

I have a function that removes the front element from a queue and adds a new one to the rear. Is there an agreed-upon name for this action? If so, I can't find it.

I'm using "CycleQueue()", but that feels wrong.

Comment: Do you really need to define a function for this? If an abstraction is very shallow it may not be worth the cost of introducing it. I mean if you already have the operations *Enqueue* and *Dequeue*.

Comment: I suppose I don't need to, no. I am pretty religious about Don't Repeat Yourself; maybe too much. In this situation the overhead isn't an issue, so I can't live with myself unless I make the abstraction.

Comment: Remember that for any good practice: The novice is unaware of it. The journeyman uses it slavishly. The master uses it thoughtfully.